# How do I get the date 30 days from when a user selects from calendar in JS

Tags: javascript, date

In my JavaScript, I have a calendar. The selection will look something like "04-01-2020". I have a function that checks if the from date and to date are over 30 days. How do I get the date 30 days from that date? I'm guessing I'd have to convert the "mm-dd-yyyy" to javascript's date format before converting back somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
var oldDate = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date('2020-06-17').getDate() - 30));

console.log((oldDate.getMonth()+1)+"-"+oldDate.getDate()+"-"+oldDate.getFullYear());
```

Comment: Is there a way to get ```oldDate``` to be the format "mm-dd-yyyy" only? When I run it now, it gives me ```5/17/2020, 2:17:22 PM```

Comment: I have changed the format. Is this what you expected?

Comment: '2020-06-17' will be parsed as UTC, the other methods are all local so the result will be 1 day off depending on the time of day that the code is executed and the local timezone offset.

Comment: @AshikPaul For some reason, it will always be starting on May or ```5```, even if I change ```new Date('2020-06-17').getDate()``` to ```new Date('2020-02-17').getDate()```. Do you know why this is?